# How to check if my multimeter's fuse is damaged?

Tags: multimeter, test, fuses

I recently bought a cheap multimeter. I played around measuring stuff on simple circuits and I think I managed to damage it as I don't seem to be able to measure current anymore (always get zero amperes, although voltage, resistance, and the rest work just fine). I googled around and found out that it is not uncommon for beginners to blow their multimeter's fuse when trying to measure current the wrong way; I think I've fallen in this category.

Though I would like to confirm, so I took out the fuse from the multimeter. I'm not sure how a damaged fuse should look like, yet it doesn't look broken, it is nice and clear and a very fine wire is visible. It is around 2cm long and on it is written *F200mAL250V* which I guess means that it is a fast glass 200mA fuse rated for 250V.

Can I use my multimeter to find out if the fuse is broken? What metering mode should I use for this particular fuse and what should I look for?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you find that the question deserves a downvote, please elaborate a bit in a comment; I will try to improve it. As I'm new to the world of electronics I'd like to gain some reputation in this website and use it more often.

Comment: It's off-topic. See the FAQ.

Comment: @LeonHeller How is the proper way to test a defective electronic part off topic? Is repair not apart of design?

Comment: @LeonHeller Sorry, I don't understand that either. All the "related" questions that I see on the right column right now seem to be of quite similar nature. Oh well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Measure the resistance of the fuse. If it's very low (close to 0 ohms), it's still good. If it's very high (open circuit), it's blown.

A 200 mA fuse should have a very fine wire visible inside the glass. If it's completely clear, the wire is gone (blown).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the fuse must be blown because the multimeter indicates an open circuit. But, there *is* a very fine wire inside the glass which is visible. Is that a contradiction?

Comment: I edited the question to include the fact that the fine wire appears

Comment: No, the wire can be broken near one end, with most of it still visible in the glass.

Comment: If it measures open circuit it's broken. You sure the wire is fully intact? http://media.photobucket.com/image/recent/tbizzle/fuse.jpg

Comment: At least I'm sure that it is not cut in the middle like in the picture, maybe there is something in the very edges that I cannot see. It *is* a little saturated though (blue-ish to red-ish).

Comment: I opened my multimeter to check the fuse. It's a ceramic fuse, so it's hard to tell if it's burned. Though, there is a little discoloration on one end. The multimeter reads near 0 (0.03ohm) when touching the leads. The functions seem fine, but does not measure current at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may find there is a second, spare, fuse inside the multimeter. That was the case with a cheap analog multimeter I bought at Radio Shack.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually use the resistance measurement function to check -- connect the (usually) red ohms measurement wire to the current range input (also usually red) -- no need to connect the black wire.

If it reads < 10 ohm, then the current range (and fuse) is OK; if it reads open, then the fuse is blown.